# How Do I Disable a broken Headphone jack Without Reconizing the Headphone name?

Tags: headphones, headphone-jack

I've tried previous methods to try and revert the headphone jack to the system speakers, but the system does not recognize that headphones identification. however, the jack is still active. I have to use Bluetooth headphones to override this, but it would be nice if there were no lag. (FYI: clicking on the sound dock does nothing, because its only my Bluetooth headphones.) here's some bonus info: the device I'm on is a monitor that acts like a laptop. it Registers the headphone jack like its own system name. it doesn't register other sound options, in the sound dock. I'm writing this because my headphone jack Broke in the headphone jack area. and it would be lovely to get speaker sound.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Hope this helps. I'm not sure how to use windows OS detection.
Edition         Windows 10 Home
Version         20H2
Installed on ‎3/‎31/‎2021
OS build         19042.1288
Experience Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.3920.0